# Django rest framework add extra context in response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using a updateapiview to the update my user information. This is my view

```
class UserUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
   serializer_class = UserUpdateSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    print(self.kwargs['pk'])
    return User.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

  def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
    if self.get_object() != request.user:
        return Response({'error': 'permission denied'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    print(request.data['password'])
    request.data['password'] = make_password(request.data['password'])
    instance = super(UserUpdateView, self).partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return instance
```

This is my serializer

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)

  def validate_username(self, username):
    if User.objects.filter(username=username):
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Username already exists!!')
    return username

  def validate_email(self, email):
    if User.objects.filter(email=email):
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Email already exists!!')
    return email

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('pk', 'username', 'password', 'email')
    read_only_fields = ('pk',)
```

I am getting the data updated and returned successfully. But I want to add some field like message with content 'successfully updated' on successful updation of the user profile. I searched if there is any way to perform this but can't find the appropriate way to do it (alike get_context_data method in django). So, is there any way to perform the above task ??

Question 2:
How to prevent the self user ( i.e if has a email sample@gmail.com and if user clicks udpate with the same email, it should not raise an error that username already exists, I guess this can be done with self.instance (but not sure how actually to implement it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of DRF you are using but in the latest 3.9.0 `UpdateAPIView` uses `UpdateModelMixin`, which [returns Response object](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/2b6245db5359571f10d27ace16473d70e160dce2/rest_framework/mixins.py#L77) instead of instance. So you can modify data before returning.

```
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
    if self.get_object() != request.user:
        return Response({'error': 'permission denied'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    print(request.data['password'])
    request.data['password'] = make_password(request.data['password'])
    response = super(UserUpdateView, self).partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    response.data['message'] = 'Successfully updated'
    return response
```

Regarding your second question you can exclude the current user using `self.instance`.

```
def validate_email(self, email):
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(id=self.instance.id).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Email already exists!!')
    return email
```

Comment: Thanks @UnholyRaven